# About the Mongodb sharding?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a collection, like is:

```
 { name:aaa,
   nick:bbbb,
   item:[{item_id:123456，price:13.00},
           {item_id:833457，price:12.00},
         .....
        }]
 }
```

I had set the collection to sharding , the sharding key is name and item.item_id. If I had save many many items into collection.

I have a question:

If these data saved to one collection, not contain a embeded document, will lead to sharding. But I have save these data to embeded document(the example), can sharding or not sharding?

Thanks.

Comment: first there is no such thing as "child collection" so you will need to explain exactly what you mean by that. but secondly your shard key doesn't seem to match your document - there is no (top level) field called "item_id" in your document.

Comment: Hi ,Asya Kamsky, the "child collection" is embeded document.  the sharding key is name and item.item_id.

Comment: which "item.item_id" would be in the shard key?  There are as many of them as there are elements in the array - I don't think this is a very good schema/sharding plan.  Remember that sharding distributes documents and the entire array (what you call child collection) is just part of its document.